# Create a subset by filtering on Year

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a sample dataset as shown below:

```
| Id | Year | Price |
|----|------|-------|
| 1  | 2000 | 10    |
| 1  | 2001 | 12    |
| 1  | 2002 | 15    |
| 2  | 2000 | 16    |
| 2  | 2001 | 20    |
| 2  | 2002 | 22    |
| 3  | 2000 | 15    |
| 3  | 2001 | 19    |
| 3  | 2002 | 26    |
```

I want to subset the dataset so that I can consider the values only for last two years. I want to create a variable 'end_year' and pass a year value to it and then use it to subset original dataframe to take into account only the last two years. Since I have new data coming, so I wanted to create the variable. I have tried the below code but I'm getting error.

```
end_year="2002"
df1=df[(df['Year'] >= end_year-1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, `Year` is type `object` in the raw data. We should first cast it to `int` and then compare with numeric `end_year`:

```py
df.Year=df.Year.astype(int) # cast `Year` to `int`
end_year=2002 # now we can use `int` here too
df1=df[(df['Year'] >= end_year-1)]
```

|  | Id | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2001 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 2002 | 15 |
| 4 | 2 | 2001 | 20 |
| 5 | 2 | 2002 | 22 |
| 7 | 3 | 2001 | 19 |
| 8 | 3 | 2002 | 26 |

Comment: I had tried this before but I keep getting the same error:  '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. Just to note that the 'Year' column in my original dataset is of object data type.

Comment: Ok I've edited the answer to deal with `Year` being the wrong type.